# Sqlalchemy simple query filter doesn't work. It returns all rows

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am using a simple sql query like this

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id="Some ID"
```

so in Python SQLAlchemy like this

```
results = session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.id=="Some ID").all()
```

But it returns all rows in the table. In fact if I replace `"Some ID"` value with something random which doesn't even exist in the column it also returns all the rows. Quite weird for me.
Anything I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: why in the query you have just id while in the filter you just use user_id?

Comment: and I assume from the way you write https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html that you set tablename as MyTable or?

Comment: and id is a primary key or what is it?

Comment: @feedpad its not a primary key in this table. The MyTable is the schema class which I created that refers to the table name of course

Comment: could it be that your class definition columns and types (data type and constraints (pk, etc.)) doesn't match exactly the definitions in the corresponding table if created independently?I suspect it is an input(s) problem, not a sqla problem.

Comment: Please provide the model class, and try checking what the query roughly is, by dropping the `all()` from the end and printing the query.